# d3.js geo - rendering svg path

Tags: svg, d3.js, geojson

I'd like to create choropleth map of Czech Republic. Inspired by this article http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606, I have created this
http://jsfiddle.net/1duds8tz/2/

```
var width = 960;
var height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
var offset = [width / 2, height / 2];

var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(6000).center([15.474, 49.822]).translate(offset);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

queue().defer(d3.json, "..map.geojson").await(ready);

function ready(error, reg) {
    var group = svg.selectAll("g").data(reg.features).enter().append("g");
    group.append("path").attr("d", path).attr("fill", "none").attr("stroke", "#222");
}
```

When I tried to fill svg path with some color, I ended on this
http://jsfiddle.net/1duds8tz/3/

```
        group.append("path").attr("d", path).attr("fill", "red").attr("stroke", "#222");
```

There are odd values in path d attribute. 
My GeoJSON data must be somehow faulty but I can't figure what is wrong.

Everything looks right here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4e51227dd83be8c2311d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your geoJSON is corrupted and as a result your polygons are being drawn as the interiors of an infinitely bounded polygon. That's why when you attempt to give a fill to the path, it goes beyond the extent of the screen but still displays the border just fine. I tried to reverse the winding order of your coordinates array, and that seemed to fix all of them except for "Brno-venkov", which might be the source of your problems (especially given its administrative shape).

I'd suggest going back to where you created the original GeoJSON and try to re-export it with simplification. If you want to reverse the coordinates on your GeoJSON to correct the winding order, that's pretty simple:

```
 geodata = d3.selectAll("path").data();
 for (x in geodata) {geodata[x].geometry.coordinates[0] = geodata[x].geometry.coordinates[0].reverse()}
```

But this won't fix the problem polygon, nor will *not* reversing its coordinates.

Comment: Perfect! I used KML file from Czech statistical office and converted it by QGIS (and later by http://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/) to GeoJSON. Now its working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are familiar with svg manipulation you can try [geojson2svg](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg). This allows you manipulate svg in standard way but you have to code a little more. In case your application requires d3 for many other purpose then d3 is best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem with Mapzen's .geojson files.

.reverse()-ing isn't good enough, if you can't make sure all your data has the same winding order.

I solved it with this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-rewind

1. You'll need to have `npm` & `require` available
2. Install it, and save it to your project

   `npm i -g geojson-rewind`
3. Import it, to make it useable

   `var rewind = require('geojson-rewind');`
4. Use it on the data, in this case:

   `req = rewind(req);`

**Tip:** If you are working with static data, you can do this only once on the console, and you're good to go.